# How can query be formed to select based on element value

Tags: xslt, select

We have an xml document with Invoices/Invoice/[asst. elements], using xslt call template we need to sum InvoiceAmounts for matching InvoiceNumbers.

Input xml file:

```
    <Invoices>   
     <Invoice>  
      <InvoiceNumber>351510</InvoiceNumber> 
      <InvoiceAmount>137.50</InvoiceAmount> 
     </Invoice>   
     <Invoice>  
      <InvoiceNumber>351510</InvoiceNumber> 
      <InvoiceAmount>362.50</InvoiceAmount> 
     </Invoice>   
     <Invoice>  
      <InvoiceNumber>351511</InvoiceNumber> 
      <InvoiceAmount>239.50</InvoiceAmount> 
     </Invoice>  
    </Invoices>
```

I found a select statement that returns the total sum of the InvoiceAmounts for the entire document, but need to filter that down to a sum based on the InvoiceNumber, as there could be more than one invoice with the same InvoiceNumber in the Invoices document.

This returns a total sum:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/*[local-name()='Invoices']/*[local-name()='Invoice']/*[local-name()='InvoiceAmount'])" />
```

According to my research this query below should filter the results to one InvoiceNumber, but it is not.  So we added a parameter to this template, p1, and formated the query below.  Is there another way to format this select to grab a total only for those InvoiceNumbers = $p1?  Having tried many variations of this, still cannot get the expected results.  Is there a way to add the $p1 variable to the select to filter the results?

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/*[local-name()='Invoices']/*[local-name()='Invoice'][local-name()='InvoiceAmount' = $p1]/*[local-name()='InvoiceAmount'])" />
```

Expected results:

```
<Invoices>
 <Invoice>
  <InvoiceNumber>351510</InvoiceNumber>
  <InvoiceAmount>500.00</InvoiceAmount>
 </Invoice>
 <Invoice>
  <InvoiceNumber>351510</InvoiceNumber>
  <InvoiceAmount>500.00</InvoiceAmount>
 </Invoice>
 <Invoice>
  <InvoiceNumber>351511</InvoiceNumber>
  <InvoiceAmount>239.50</InvoiceAmount>
 </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

Thank you for your consideration.
Tom

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy and most efficient solution, using keys.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="InvoiceAmount">
        <InvoiceAmount>
            <xsl:value-of 
               select="sum(../../Invoice[InvoiceNumber=
                   current()/parent::*/InvoiceNumber]/InvoiceAmount)"/>
       </InvoiceAmount>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces:

```
<Invoices>   
     <Invoice>  
         <InvoiceNumber>351510</InvoiceNumber> 
         <InvoiceAmount>500</InvoiceAmount> 
     </Invoice>   
     <Invoice>  
         <InvoiceNumber>351510</InvoiceNumber> 
         <InvoiceAmount>500</InvoiceAmount> 
     </Invoice>   
     <Invoice>  
         <InvoiceNumber>351511</InvoiceNumber> 
         <InvoiceAmount>239.5</InvoiceAmount> 
     </Invoice>  
</Invoices>
```

**Note:** Formatting money is left as an exercise. See [`xsl:decimal-format`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#format-number).

Comment: lwburk, **many** thanks to you for responding to my post, very appreciated.  You make it look easy.  In the end we need only the <InvoiceAmount> value outputted for one InvoiceNumber that is passed in as a parameter.  Although the sample I provided shows that variable it was not stated as a condition of the solution.  I apologize to you for that.  I was working with your solution til late in the night yesterday but was unable to add a parameter to your match expression; I know this should be easy.  Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation can be factors of magnitude more efficient** than if keys are not used -- especially with big XML documents:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kInvAmmtByNumber" match="InvoiceAmount"
  use="../InvoiceNumber"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="InvoiceAmount/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "sum(key('kInvAmmtByNumber', ../../InvoiceNumber))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Invoices>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceNumber>351510</InvoiceNumber>
        <InvoiceAmount>137.50</InvoiceAmount>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceNumber>351510</InvoiceNumber>
        <InvoiceAmount>362.50</InvoiceAmount>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceNumber>351511</InvoiceNumber>
        <InvoiceAmount>239.50</InvoiceAmount>
    </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Invoices>
   <Invoice>
      <InvoiceNumber>351510</InvoiceNumber>
      <InvoiceAmount>500</InvoiceAmount>
   </Invoice>
   <Invoice>
      <InvoiceNumber>351510</InvoiceNumber>
      <InvoiceAmount>500</InvoiceAmount>
   </Invoice>
   <Invoice>
      <InvoiceNumber>351511</InvoiceNumber>
      <InvoiceAmount>239.5</InvoiceAmount>
   </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, your work is very nice.  In my case we need to filter the selected nodes from within the match expression, to include only the InvoiceNumbers that match a parameter value containing a specified Invoice number.  Is it possible to add a variable, $InvNbr for example, to the match expression?  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>